# Local hardware specialists tested my HDDs for me, PC came back slow / hanging randomly

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista

I was concerned that my HDD may have been about to fail after I heard a couple of clicks (perhaps I was overly paranoid, but it's almost deadline time at University and I'm a Computing student - so having a PC available is a big deal!)

I bought myself a 2Tb HDD so I could do a disk image back up, and I also sent it to my local computer repair place to take a look.

They gave me it back, after testing the HDD, and said that it was 100% fine. (I've not heard the noise again, so I guess it was just a fluke) They said they took the HDDs out to test on their test bed, and didn't even boot up my PC.

I got it back a couple of hours ago, and it's hanging a whole lot (it had no problems before) and also being pretty slow. It doesn't seem to be very related to what I'm doing. It was hanging a few times in Windows Explorer, a couple of times in Skyrim, and once in iTunes. The hangs have been any time from a few seconds to a minute or two.

I ran malwarebytes and it found nothing.

It was a little slower than usual on the 'Verifying DMI pool data' on startup (It was usually just a second or two, but I noticed it being maybe twenty seconds one time, and five or ten another)

Any thoughts?

The PC had no problems before I took it in to be checked.

**Edit:**

I'm receiving the error 'APPHANGB1' in windows explorer.

Comment: What interface are your HDD's? IDE/PATA or SATA? Thinking along the lines of HDD detection or faulty/damaged cable. It might be worth running a memory test just to confirm it's not your RAM, lots of tools on [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info).

Comment: I'm not sure. Its a RAID. Total 1Tb.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever someone opens a case and removes items, or even puts a computer in a car, there is always the possibility that something got moved or knocked around. Because we know this happened, the obvious thing to do is to remove and reseat any add-on cards and memory, and check the cabling. Make sure the fans are still turning, especially ensure that the fans can turn and are not obstructed by a wire.

Comment: I shut my PC down, and took out the cables connected to the HDDs, and then placed them back. My PC now won't start up properly. It hangs for ages on the starting windows part and then just (sometimes with a BSOD which lasts literally about 0.3 of a second) starts trying to start up from scratch again :/

Comment: Oh and the fans are all fine

Comment: try booting the computer using a linux livecd distro. possibly even with the HDDs unplugged. See if you can use it or if you see similar instability. This will eliminate (or implicate) the HDD.

Comment: Using the windows boot screen (pressing F8) you will see an option to 'Disable restart on failure' - this will allow you to see what's contained on the BSOD (windows STOP error). Main thing to note is what's mentioned on the top left, and google it.